# Sql Server 2005 Copy Multiple Result Sets

Tags: sql-server-2005, resultset

How Can i copy multiple result sets at the same time?

for example if i were to execute the below code:

```
select 'a'
select 'b'
select 'c'
```

how can i copy all 3 results so i can then paste them into excel? I tried holding down shift and selecting all 3 result sets but it only copies the last one i select.

Comment: Copy them to what?  Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: copy them so i can then paste them into excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'a'
union all
select 'b'
union all
select 'c'
```

This will return one result set that you can copy and paste wherever you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

You can select

- Query'>'Results to'> 'Results to text' or
- Query'>'Results to'> 'Results to file'